# How to transfer a string over LAN?

Tags: c#, .net, lan

I have two applications which are running on computers on a LAN. I need to transfer a string between them but I can't do this because the Socket.Send method doesn't accept a string. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

transfer your String into a Byte-array with the following function:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)
```

ByteArrays can be handled by the Socket.send function.

On the other side, convert your Byte-array into a string again:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)
```

Comment: But how I can to convert It to string in the other application? Oh thanks. This is what I need

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your string into a byte array on the fly as you send it:

```
_socket.Send( System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( datastring ) );
```

At the receiving end, you convert it back into a string like this:

```
datastring = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
               bytesBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesReceived );
```